# Get parent column value from parent column id

Tags: sql, oracle, join, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to get the data from a parent id and get the `PARENT_CODE` result (from column `CD_CODE`) from a query, according to the parent column it is equal to the main id. But I don't know how I can do it, I saw and read about using CONNECT BY PRIOR, but I was not successful in the result.

My table:

```
ID   PARENT_ID  CD_CODE
-------------------------------
675             9000000000000
676             2000000000001
677             6000000000003
678             1000000000006
679       676   2100000000008
680       677   6400000000009
681       677   6300000000002
682       678   1200000000009
683       677   6100000000000
684       676   2200000000004
685       675   9100000000006
```

What I need, is to get the PARENT_CODE (but this column doesn't exist):

```
ID   PARENT_ID    PARENT_CODE   CD_CODE
----------------------------------------------
675                             9000000000000
676                             2000000000001
677                             6000000000003
678                             1000000000006
679       676   2000000000001   2100000000008
680       677   6000000000003   6400000000009
681       677   6000000000003   6300000000002
682       678   1000000000006   1200000000009
683       677   6000000000003   6100000000000
684       676   2000000000001   2200000000004
685       675   9000000000000   9100000000006
```

SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, PARENT_ID, CD_CODE 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a self-join:

```
select t.*, p.cd_code parent_code
from mytable t
left join mytable p on p.id = t.parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB! I didn't think about self join, actually it was a pretty simple solution, thank you very much.